# HTML5/Javascript canvas - draw circle with 7 partitions

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need draw circle with 7 partitions.

I have already this code done:

**HTML**

```
<body style="background:#F6A631;">
    <canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="730" height="730"></canvas>  
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var services = ["paragraphs", "paragraphs", "paragraphs", "paragraphs", "paragraphs", "paragraphs", "paragraphs"];

  function serviceCircle() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var outsideRadius = 360;
      var textRadius = 280;
      var insideRadius = 220;

      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,720,720); // 720 - 360 - 180 (500 - 250)


      ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;

      ctx.font = 'bold 18px Tahoma';

      for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffc000";

        ctx.translate(360 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 360 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
        // ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
        var text = services[i];
        ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
        ctx.restore();
      } 

      //Arrow
      ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  draw();
```

My result - [Image](http://skidka.tj/circle.html)
I need this one. With hover on partition and changing it's background.

Don't have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure what parts you need help with--I'm guessing its wordwrapping. First divide each label into separate words using `var words=services[0].split(' ')`. Then use `context.measureText` to get the width of each word.  Then you can word-wrap those word(s) to fit into the partitions. You will find `context.textAlign='center'` useful in centering your wrapped word(s).

Comment: Text problem solved. I need circle with 7 partitions with border and on hover changing background of partition.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's some pseudo-code to highlight the partition under the mouse...**

Calc the angle of mouse vs centerpoint using:

```
// mx,my are mouse coordinates, cx,cy are centerpoint coordinates
var angle=Math.atan2(my-cy,mx-cx).
```

Calc the distance to the mouse from the centerpoint using:

```
var distance=Math.sqrt((mx-cx)*(mx-cx)+(my-cy)*(my-cy)).
```

If `angle` is between the starting & ending angle of a partition and `distance` is between the inner and outer radius then the mouse is in that partition.

```
var isInsidePartition1 = 
      angle>partition1StartingAngle &&
      angle<=partition1EndingAngle &&
      distance>=innerRadius &&
      distance<=outerRadius;
```

Now redraw everything (nothing highlighted);

And finally, if the mouse 'hit' a partition, redraw just the 'hit' partition in your highlighted color.